# Доступ к файлам в UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

Есть ли в UWP возможность создавать папки/файлы в любом желаемом месте, также как это делается в WPF. Например, DirectoryInfo dir = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

Мне известно, что UWP это песочница и может иметь доступ только к определённым файлам. Но может есть какой-то вариант. FileSavePicker, я так понимаю, работает только с диалоговым окном, верно? Как я понял, StorageFolder и StorageFile работают только с локальными папками.

Comment: Это пробовали: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefrompathasync#Windows_Storage_StorageFile_GetFileFromPathAsync_System_String_ ?

Comment: И это ещё прочитайте: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations

Comment: (Broad Filesystem Access)

Comment: Спасибо, Андрей. Ваш совет помог найти решение. Хотелось бы еще спросить, стоит ли переход с WPF на UWP? Приложение работает исключительно на Desktop PC.

Comment: Ну я особого смысла в таком переходе не вижу

Answer (score 1):

Андрей, спасибо. Нашел решение:

1) Код:

```
public async void Save()
{
    try
    {
        StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"F:\Downloads\");
        StorageFolder newFolder = await folder.CreateFolderAsync("New Folder", CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(ex.Message);
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

2) В Package.appxmanifest надо добавить:

в разделе Package

```
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
```

в резделе Capabilities

```
<rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
```

3) Настройки >> Конфиденциальность >> Файловая система >> Разрешить доступ к файлам